# wordpress filter run only to current page it dont return result from 1-st page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

```
<pre><code>
session_start();
$countClick = 0;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
$s = $_GET['news_search'];
$news_tags = $_GET['news_tag'];
$newsCategory = $_GET['news_category'];
$beratungsfeldeCategory = $_GET['beratungsfelder_category'];
$branchesCategory = $_GET['branches_category'];
$jobsCategory = $_GET['job_category'];
$postsYear = $_GET['news_years'];
$categoriesSelected = [];
if (!isset($_SESSION['news_filter_attr'])) {
    $_SESSION['news_filter_attr'] = [
        'news_search'=>'',
        'news_tag'=>'',
        'news_category'=>'',
        'beratungsfelder_category'=>'',
        'branches_category'=>'',
        'job_category'=>'',
        'clicked'=>$countClick
    ];
}


$oldFilters = $_SESSION['news_filter_attr'];
$newFilters = $oldFilters;
if ($newsCategory) {
    array_push($categoriesSelected, $newsCategory);
    $newFilters['news_category'] = $newsCategory;

}
if ($beratungsfeldeCategory) {
    array_push($categoriesSelected, $beratungsfeldeCategory);
    $newFilters['beratungsfelder_category'] = $beratungsfeldeCategory;
}
if ($branchesCategory) {
    array_push($categoriesSelected, $branchesCategory);
    $newFilters['branches_category'] = $branchesCategory;
}
if ($jobsCategory) {
    array_push($categoriesSelected, $jobsCategory);
    $newFilters['job_category'] = $jobsCategory;
}
if ($s) {
    $newFilters['news_search'] = $s;
}
$differences = array_diff_assoc($newFilters, $oldFilters);

if (is_array($differences) && count($differences) > 0) {
    $paged = 1;
    $newFilters['clicked']++;
}else {
    $paged = $paged;
}



echo '<pre>';
    var_dump('old'.print_r($oldFilters));
    var_dump('new'.print_r($newFilters));
echo '</pre>';

$_SESSION['news_filter_attr'] = $newFilters;
$args = array(
    's' => $s,
    'order' => 'DESC', // Also support: ASC
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' =>$paged
);
</code></pre>
```

i expect from this code  when i have called a new item in filter it should start apearing the results from page 1 then i will be able to go what page i want to go, in this code i provided there when i call twice the same filter item the first one apear results from page 1 and the second call run to the current page example page/8